# How to add HTML5 custom data-* attribute to Laravel 4 blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

This line:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'AnyController@hello', 'class'=> 'hello']) }}
```

Will result to:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/hello" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hello">
```

However, I wanted to add HTML5 custom data-* attribute, such:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/hello" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hello" data-abide>
```

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 4 you can add custom attributes directly to the array.

```
{{ Form::open(array(
         'action'     => 'AController@index', 
         'class'      => 'hello', 
         'data-abide' => true
     ))
}}
```

I am unsure whether Laravel will place in attributes that have no value via the `Form` facade.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if its a change in laravel, but

```
{{ Form::open(array(
     'action'     => 'AController@index', 
     'class'      => 'hello', 
     'data-abide' => true
  ))
}}
```

results in

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/hello" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hello" data-abide="1">
```

To get the the results you asked for use:

```
{{ Form::open(array(
     'action'     => 'AController@index', 
     'class'      => 'hello', 
     'data-abide' => ''
  ))
}}
```

which results in

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8000/hello" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="hello" data-abide>
```